SQLAlchemy relationships
How to properly do the relation like 'one user has many friends'?
I did it like this, but do not know whether it is a bad code / approach. Maybe it's better to save just ID's of friends? Thank you!
class User(Base, TimeStampMixin, TableNameMixin):
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(INTEGER, primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(255), nullable=False)
    balance: Mapped[float] = mapped_column(REAL, nullable=False)


    friends: Mapped[list["UserFriend"]] = relationship(back_populates="user", secondary="user_friends")


class UserFriend(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user_friends'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(INTEGER, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("users.id"), nullable=False)
    friend_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("users.id"), nullable=False)


Maybe it's better to save just ID's of friends? No, that's a bad way to do it.  This way is fine.

I agree with @JohnGordon, this is exacyly what a many-to-many relationship is used for in SQL, so the models you shared are precisely how I would do it.

Don't forget you probably want a uniqueness constraint on the combination of user_id and friend_id, since it makes no sense to befriend someone twice.

I need to add additionally 'referrer' column. It's a person who invited you. Should it be connected with 'friends'? or it's self-referenced independent? Thank you so much @JohnGordon @M.O. !! I tried like this (it works, but I deleted 'friends' in this case. so probably it's a really bad approach):
referrer_id: Mapped[Optional[int]] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=True)
    referrer: Mapped[Optional['User']] = relationship(
        'User',
        remote_side=[id],
        back_populates='referrals'
    )

